# Adb command to check if the device is encrypted

Tags: android, encryption, adb

I would like to check directly from ADB (on a non-rooted device) if the encryption is enabled or not.

Do you know if there is a command returning this kind of result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As simple as `adb shell getprop ro.crypto.state`